# Powershell not finding a file with a .py extension

Tags: python, powershell

I am using Zed Shaw's "Learn Python the Hard Way" and have gotten Python to work.  I made a file and saved it as ex1.py.  I type the command

`python ex1.py`

This does not recognize the file like it should and instead gives me this

`can't open file 'ex1.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

I have checked and double-checked it.  There is definitely a ex1.py file saved in my Local Disk (C:).  None of the common errors on his tutorial include mine.  Any tips?

Comment: Double-check your current working directory, and the directory in which your source code is saved.

Comment: Your script is directly in `C:`??

Comment: What happens if you do `dir ex1.py` ? If you get an error, you are in the wrong directory.

Comment: Along with tiger you could check `Get-Location` to see if it is C:

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly indicate that the file is in the current working directory.

Try this:

```
python ./ex1.py
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work finally, I had it in a folder under the path

`C:\Users\MyUser\PythonTest\ex1.py`

This was wrong, however when I made it

`C:\Users\MyUser\ex1.py`

It worked, thanks for all the help!